# Find a non-abelian group of order 72

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I don't know how to find a non-abelian group. I know that $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3}$ is a group of order of 72 but it's abelian so how do i find one that isn't abelian? Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $n> 2$, the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ is a non-abelian group of order $2n$.

Comment: so $ D_{72}$ is non-abelian?

Comment: It depends on the notation. Some authors write $D_{36}$ for the dihedral group of order $72$, and some others write $D_{72}$. When you see $D_n$ you can't be sure about the definition, but if you see $D_{2n}$ it pretty much always means the group of order $2n$. In any case, all dihedral groups are non-abelian except for the one of order $2$.

Comment: You're right, it should be $n>2$.

Answer (score 1):

$S_3×Z_{12}$,$D_{36}$ these can be your two nonisomorphic non abelian grouops of order 72

Answer (score 1):

The "how" can be a little tricky, though in this case it is pretty easy as we know $\;S_3\;$ isn't abelian, so then $\;G:=S_3\times C_{12}\;$ is non abelian, eventhough the second factor is ( the cyclic group of order $\;12\;$).

Another general way:  if you have two non-trivial groups $\;H,K\;$ and a non-trivial homomorphism $\;H\to\text{Aut}\,(K)\;$ , their semidirect product is non-abelian.